# Site wide information data

Tags: 7, forms

I'm using many information data on my site. I have some blocks with the main informations like address and phone numbers, but also I have some blocks with Quick Response code, geolocations (latitude, longitude) etc. There is about 15 this kind of details.

I wrote a simple module which allows me to define them in one place and save all of them as a one variable (array), so if I need any contact detail in any block template file, I just call e.g: $contact_details['qr_code'] to get it.

It's working and it is very useful, but I'm just wondering what do you think about that? Maybe I spent couple hours unnecessarily, because this kind of module already exists, or maybe I did not need any module at all, because for example: I should create a page with as many fields as I need, and then create my blocks with views?

I think many people would be intersted where to store all their contact informations and use them to build any content they need, for example blocks.

there is a small cutting of my module output:

[image: a form with site wide contact details]

Comment: How about you upload your module to drupal.com? ;) I'd like to use it.

Comment: I think it's too simple for drupal.com :) but If you or anyone will want to take a look, then I can send it by email, no problem.

Comment: Then put it on github :-) I might fork it and turn it into a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no module that does this for you.

I think this is a sensible approach.  I am doing the same thing myself, storing the array with site-wide persistant data using the built-in [`function variable_set()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) to save, and then I use [`function variable_get()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) to retrieve the data.

I don't think saving site wide information in fields is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. That's why I wrote this module. I think it's very useful and I was very surprised when I can't find anything like that on drupal.org

Answer (score 1):

The is no a bad solutions, when they actually work for you.

My approach would be:

1.Create a node type with all types of fields needed.

2.Create one node of that type and fill out with data.

3.Create custom module, with several blocks returning field_view_value() of fields that node has.